# Cannot add Bar Button Item to Navigation Controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am building a todo list app to get more practice with tableViews and delegates. I have embedded my primary tableViewController in a Navigation Controller and I have created two additional view controllers, one for adding a task and one fore editing a task. When I attempt to add a bar button item to one of the additional view controllers (done, trash, etc), Xcode is placing the item in a tab bar along the bottom of the screen and when I run the app, those items are not visible. I have changed the type of device I am working on, relaunched Xcode entirely, and I cannot figure out why this is happening. I have added a screenshot below and [here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/toDoList) is a link to the repo. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

first you need to add **Navigation Item** in Navigation Bar. then add UIBarButton in Navigation Item.

[image: Navigation Item]

[image: full example]

Answer (score 2):

Programatically you can add as:

```
        let shareBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(self.shareClass))

        let downloadBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(string: UIImage(named: "your_image_name")), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.downloadClass))

        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([shareBarButtonItem, downloadBarButtonItem], animated: true)
```